# How would one code test and set behavior without a special hardware instruction?

Tags: synchronization, primitive, test-and-set

Most of the implementations I find require a hardware instruction to do this.  However I strongly doubt this is required (if it is, I can't figure out why...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a test and set instruction to get mutual exclusion locking, if thats what you're asking.
Dijkstra described the first mutual exclusion algorithm I am aware of, in 1965. The title of the paper was "Solution of a problem in concurrent programming control", search Google for a copy near you. The original algorithm required no special support from the hardware at all, but providing an atomic instruction in the CPU dramatically improves the performance.

Test-and-set, atomic swap, and load-linked + store-conditional are all common primitives for CPUs to provide. All can be used to implement mutual exclusion, which can then be used to implement whatever locking semantics you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a cross-arch way to do so, and are using gcc, then you can use gcc's atomic builtins:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Calling these will result in a hardware specific machine instruction for the current build architecture. On those that do not support them, the compile will fail. (I think...)